# What goes on behind the scenes in .reloadData() in terms of cell indexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a collection view and every time I select the cell I change the cell background color to red. Simple enough:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

This works absolutely fine. When I select the top 3 cells going from left to right, the background color changes exactly as I expect:

[image]

However If I reload the collectionView after I select the cell the selection ordering begins to behave strangely. When I select the same top 3 cells in the same order from left to right, different cells become selected:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

[image]

Apple's documentation is cryptic. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

They say that "This causes the collection view to discard any currently visible items (including placeholders) and recreate items based on the current state of the data source object. " But this makes me think that upon calling reloadData() the collectionViewCells would go back to gray and not jump indexPaths.

Can anyone explain what is going on in reloadData() to make the cell selection at index path ordering so strange?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UICollectionViewDataSource cellForItemAt` and `UICollectionView dequeueReusableCell`.

Comment: You should also read the [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334).

Comment: Hi @rmaddy After reading through the documentation you suggested and the links you provided, I've come to understand that the reordering has to do with the collection view layout. However, Im unable to find exactly how reloadData affects the layout. Any suggestions for further reading?

Comment: Nope. It has nothing to do with layout or even `reloadData` actually. Simply scrolling your collection view (if you have enough items) will cause your issue. It's caused by cell reuse.

Comment: @rmaddy So dequeueResuableCell returns a valid reusableView like a collection view cell. The documentation states that the "collection view places them on a reuse queue rather than deleting them when they are scrolled out of the visible bounds." But in this case, none of the cells are going out of bounds. Doesn't that mean nothing gets reused?

Comment: Reloading is the same as all of them going out of bounds. They all get reused.

Comment: You need to ensure that `cellForItemAt` returns a correctly configured cell based on the current state of the model at that indexPath.  In other words that method must explicitly set the cell to red if it should be red or gray if it should be gray. You can't assume anything about the state of the cell that is dequeued.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh! wow, really?  I've been looking for documentation on exactly what reloadData() does. but the best I can find is: "Reloads all of the data for the collection view." from Apple, which is completely unhelpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Paulw11 After reading rmaddy's response on reloading being the same as all the cells being reused, your explanation makes complete sense. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

First You need to use dequeue cell

`let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell`

And in cell you can use

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
  // Set default implementation
```

}